# Prestashop Remove id categories

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am Prestashop user im trying to find a url category solution

I need to know the process to remove the category id (Numeric) for Prestashop url.
For Example www.mydomain.com/16-myproducts

Regards

Comment: This feature is not available in PrestaShop and the best way to accomplish that is with a module.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you might do an Override of Dispatcher.php class. It pretty much depends on which version you are.

Here is how we did this at Malttt on 1.6, last year, please take care with this code, as it may be outdated, it also covers other cases (products, suppliers ...) :

```
/*
*  @author      Matt Loye <matthieu@agence-malttt.fr>
*  @copyright   2016-2017 Agence Malttt
*/

class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{
    /**
     * @var array List of default routes
     */
    public $default_routes = array(
        'supplier_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'supplier',
            'rule' =>       'supplier/{rewrite}/',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'supplier_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'manufacturer_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'manufacturer',
            'rule' =>       'manufacturer/{rewrite}/',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'manufacturer_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'cms_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'cms',
            'rule' =>       'info/{rewrite}',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'cms_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'cms_category_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'cms',
            'rule' =>       'info/{rewrite}/',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'cms_category_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'module' => array(
            'controller' => null,
            'rule' =>       'module/{module}{/:controller}',
            'keywords' => array(
                'module' =>         array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'module'),
                'controller' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'controller'),
            ),
            'params' => array(
                'fc' => 'module',
            ),
        ),
        'product_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'product',
            'rule' =>       '{category:/}{rewrite}.html',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'product_rewrite'),
                'ean13' =>          array('regexp' => '[0-9\pL]*'),
                'category' =>       array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'categories' =>     array('regexp' => '[/_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'reference' =>      array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'manufacturer' =>   array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'supplier' =>       array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'price' =>          array('regexp' => '[0-9\.,]*'),
                'tags' =>           array('regexp' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'layered_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'category',
            'rule' =>       '{rewrite}/filter{selected_filters}',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                /* Selected filters is used by the module blocklayered */
                'selected_filters' =>       array('regexp' => '.*', 'param' => 'selected_filters'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'category_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
        'category_rule' => array(
            'controller' => 'category',
            'rule' =>       '{rewrite}/',
            'keywords' => array(
                'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                'categories' =>     array('regexp' => '[/_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'category_rewrite'),
                'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```