# Prestashop remove id from category

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

i need to remove the id to my url path like: [www.site.it/4-category](http://www.site.it/4-category). I need to remove the 4.

I see that exist a payment plugin that do this. But i want only to remove it from category and not for product.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, as you didn't try anything (I mean code), you will not find help here. You can contact that paid module developers to ask for work only with categories. Or you can contact a developer (as me) to do the trick for your shop.

Comment: very funny i asked for a help

Comment: Hello Andrea, most of these modules are configurable, meaning you can choose if change the URL for categories, products, etc.

Comment: How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i know how to ask

Comment: @Andrea: Hi,

Sorry but José is right, although he linked the wrong documentation page and should have linked this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
StackOverflow is for programmers (people who code). Hence, your question is off-topic.

Your question is also a duplicate of this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704110/prestashop-remove-id-categories
Before posting, it seems you have not done your job of searching for similar question on the forum.

For non programmers:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin -> Preferences -> SEO & URLs
& update the "Route to Category" & remove the "{id}-"
this will remove the category ID from only the category.

[image]

Comment: Before posting, did you try saving the "Route to category" without id? I don't think so. The Prestashop backend will generate an error that the id is required.